# prevdepth related error only in case of abscence of whitespace

Tags: macros, pdftex, amsmath, breqn

In the file given below, I am using macros for equations and their environment. The equations use breqn package for breaking them when the width available is not sufficient. I am getting the error

> You can't use `\prevdepth' in horizontal mode.

But typing a newline between each of the 3 lines in the main document, and the error vanishes. I am not sure why this is happening.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,breqn}

\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}

\newcommand{\myeqThree}[1][]{
\begin{dmath*}
a1=b1+c1
\label{eq:Three}
\text{#1}
\end{dmath*}}

\newcommand{\myeqOne}[1][]{
\begin{dgroup*}
\begin{dmath*}
a1=b1+c1
\end{dmath*}
\begin{dmath}
a1=b1+c1
\label{eq:One}
\end{dmath}
\text{#1}
\end{dgroup*}}

\title{title1}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{section1}
\myeqThree
which gives us
\myeqOne
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I don't think that text between `\end{dmath}` and `\end{dgroup*}` is allowed.

Comment: @egreg -- do you mean `\text` or "text" (as in ordinary unmarked text)?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I tried both.

Comment: I could not find any such rule in the breqn package. Besides when I introduce newlines between the 3 lines I do not get any error. If what you say was true, the document wouldn't compile in any case, right?

Comment: What do you mean by “introducing newlines”?

Comment: '\myeqThree \n which gives us \n  \myeqOne' works perfectly, where \n is the newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual of `breqn`

> `dgroup` Like the `align` environment of `amsmath`, but with each constituent equation wrapped in a `dmath`, `dmath*`, `dseries`, or `dseries*` environment instead of being separated by `\\`. The equations are numbered with a group number. When the constituent environments are the numbered forms (`dmath` or `dseries`) they automatically switch to ‘subequations’-style numbering, i.e., something like (3a), (3b), (3c), …, depending on the current form of non-grouped equation numbers.

So your attempt cannot succeed.

If your aim is to suspend the alignment, then use `dsuspend`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,breqn}

\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}

\title{title1}

\begin{document}

\section{section1}

\begin{dgroup*}
\begin{dmath*}
a1=b1+c1
\end{dmath*}
\begin{dmath}
a1=b1+c1
\label{eq:One}
\end{dmath}
\begin{dsuspend}
some text
\end{dsuspend}
\begin{dmath*}
a1=b1+c1
\end{dmath*}
\begin{dmath}
a1=b1+c1
\end{dmath}
\end{dgroup*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My advice is to avoid `breqn`. Just for information.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand why can't the attempt succeed. 
This example is actually a minimal example that is part of a bigger file in which I need to automatically break equations when I change from single column mode to two column mode. So I am not sure whether dsuspend works in that case.

Comment: @jinkx I can't answer what is not asked for. And the problem is quite unclear, sorry.